# I want to get members count in discord bot but it gives error

Tags: node.js, count, bots, discord.js, member

I want to get members count in discord bot but it gives error. I search for it through internet for this and i don't find it!
Here is code:

```
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new Commando.Client({commandPrefix: '$'});
const TOKEN = 'here is token';
const MIN_INTERVAL = 3 * 1000;
const guild = bot.guilds.get("394805546450026496");

bot.registry.registerGroup('connectc', 'Connectc');
bot.registry.registerGroup('defaultc', 'Defaultc');
bot.registry.registerDefaults();
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands")

bot.on('ready', function(){
    console.log("Ready");
    setInterval(function(){
        var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
        var memberCountChannel = bot.channels.get("547805078787194891");
        memberCountChannel.setName("Osoby: "+ memberCount +" ");
    }, MIN_INTERVAL);
});
bot.login(TOKEN);
```

And here error:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Discord Bots\VblacqeBot\index.js:18
    var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at CommandoClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Discord Bots\VblacqeBot\index.js:18:29)    
    at CommandoClient.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at WebSocketConnection.triggerReady (C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Discord Bots\VblacqeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:125:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.checkIfReady (C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Discord Bots\VblacqeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:141:61)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Discord Bots\VblacqeBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildCreate.js:13:31)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio Code\Discord Bots\VblacqeBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

Please help me!

Comment: Is the guild id correct ? Add a `console.log(guild);` before you set the memberCount variable and check in the output if the guild is defined

Comment: do you have member intents enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your error results that the **guild** is **undefined**.
I ran the code and it's working as expected.

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, arguments) => {
   const guild = client.guilds.get("566596189827629066");
   setInterval(function () {
      var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;  
      var memberCountChannel = client.channels.get("626462657817477131");
      memberCountChannel.setName(`${guild.name} has ${memberCount} members!`);
   }, 1000);
};
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQZK6.png)

Please, double-check that **394805546450026496** is a valid guild-id and not a channel-id/user-id. If it is, check if the bot is in the mentioned guild.

Another thing, it's recommended to see if a guild is available before performing operations or reading data from it. You can check this with [guild.available](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=available).

Answer (score 2):

```
// update member
let myGuild = client.guilds.get("guilds_id_here");
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.get("channel_id_here");
memberCountChannel.setName("Member•" +memberCount+ "•User")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when the function `guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;` is called the value of guild is undefined. Are you sure `const guild = bot.guilds.get("394805546450026496");` is returning the guild correctly? Can you try logging the value of `guild` after the get is called? Im not seeing the `get(String id)` method anywhere in the discord.js documentation. Have you tried using the recommended `find()`?

Try this instead.

`const guild = bot.guilds.find(guild => {guild.id == "394805546450026496"});`

Comment: before i change to `const guild = bot.guilds.find(guild => {guild.id == "394805546450026496"});` i add `console.log(guild);` and it throw undefinied but latter it throw null

Comment: hmm, can you try but with a return statement included? ie `const guild = bot.guilds.find(guild => {return guild.id == "394805546450026496"});`

You can also try searching for the guild with other properties like its name.

If you're getting null or undefined after these changes, then odds are the guild you're looking for isn't in the guilds collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
let memberChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("802617217450901514");
memberChannel.setName("Member Count: " + message.guild.memberCount);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score -1):

//DISCORD.JS V13 MEMBERCOUNT COMMAND;

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
let guild = message.guild 
let users = guild.members.cache.filter((m) => !m.user.bot)).size;
let bots = guild.members.cache.filter((m) => m.uxer.bot).size;


let memberCount = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle(`MemberCount Information of ${guild.name}`)
 .addField("Humans", `${users}`)
 .addField("Bots", `${bots}`)
 .setColor("RANDOM")
 .setFooter({
      text: `${guild.name},
      iconURL: guild.iconURL()
    })
   message.channel.sendTyping(); 
   message.reply({
      embeds : [memberCount]
    });
```

Comment: Hello, giving result code right away is fine, but in future it would be nice if you explained your code, for others to understand what and how it does!